# asp.net change .page width

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, width

How to change the .page width value below, programmatically in the code behind page?

I need to set it based on the width of other elements on the page which keep changing based on user actions.

```
        .page
        {
            width: 1900px;
            margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
            position:fixed;
        }
```

How change that from c# code, what is the syntax for it?

Comment: .page what element is this div,or body

Comment: <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> so body i guess

Comment: you can still do it this way see update in my answer

Comment: i sugges use panel and set the width property instead of setting it in css. And then change the width in code behind.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but the does not expand the top part (the title) just the lower part the content, which is due to the master page. How can the top be affected too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery if you want to use jQuery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page').css('width', $('.otherElementClass').width()+'px');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How to execute jquery code? I have the <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in my aspx page